# Count number of lines that contain numbers after each string in a text file

Tags: python

I want to count the number of lines that contains numbers after each string. If there are consecutive strings then 0 will be affected to the first string and so on.

For example let's say I have this text file :

```
some text
120 130
1847 1853
other text
207 220
text
306 350
text with no numbers after
some other text
400 435
900 121
125 369
```

My output will be like :

```
2
1
1
0
3
```

I have a directory containing files and I want to store the results of each file in a list so I will a have a list of lists.

Here's what I have tried :

```
nb=[]  
c = 0
for filename in sorted(os.listdir("Path_to_txt_files")):
        with open(filename ,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.strip().replace(" ", "").isdigit(): 
                    c+=1                        
                    nb.append(c)
                else:
                    c=0
                    nb.append(c)
```

But this is giving me a wrong result. How can I code that ?

Comment: One option would be to use regular expressions to search for a number in each line. Here's the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively with *generator* function:

```
def count_digit_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        str_cnt = num_cnt = 0

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().replace(" ", "")
            if not line:    # skip empty lines
                continue
            if not line.isdigit():   # catch non-digit line
                if num_cnt >= 1:
                    yield num_cnt
                    str_cnt = num_cnt = 0
                str_cnt += 1
            else:
                if str_cnt > 1:
                    yield 0
                    str_cnt = 0
                num_cnt += 1
        if num_cnt:    # check trailing digit lines
            yield num_cnt
        elif str_cnt:
           yield 0


res = []
for fname in sorted(os.listdir("Path_to_txt_files")):
    gen = count_digit_lines(fname)  # generator
    res.append(list(gen))

print(res)
```

Sample output for a single file would be:

```
[[2, 1, 1, 0, 3]]
```

Comment: This gives false results when I have lines with strings at the end of the file with no numbers after.

Comment: @MejdiDallel, I've just check the case that you mentioned: added *"lines with strings at the end of the file with no numbers after"* - and it gives the same correct result. Or you meant a **few** text lines at the end?

Comment: It returns None in that case while it should return 0.

Comment: @MejdiDallel. ok, to cover that edge case - add an additional conditional branch, see my update

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
# sample file
f = '''some text
120 130
1847 1853
other text
207 220
text
306 350
text with no numbers after
some other text
400 435
900 121
125 369'''

lines = f.split('\n')

line2write = []

for line in lines:
    if not line[0].isdigit():
        line2write.append(0)
    else:
        line2write[-1] += 1
print(line2write)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 1, 0, 3]
```

Now you can write it how you like.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby


result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for k, v in groupby(infile.readlines(), lambda x: x[0].isalpha()):
        value = list(v)
        if k and len(value) > 1:
            result.append(0)
        if not k:
            result.append(len(value))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 1, 1, 0, 3]
```

---

Edit as per comment

```
result = []
for filename in list_files:
    temp = []
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for k, v in groupby(infile.readlines(), lambda x: x[0].isalpha()):
            value = list(v)
            if k and len(value) > 1:
                temp.append(0)
            if not k:
                temp.append(len(value))
    result.append(temp)
```

Comment: This solution seems to me wrong. .isalpha doesnt distiguish between '120' and 'ABC;' as it consider number and special symbols as the same

Comment: @Martin. I am actually testing only the first char. `x[0].isalpha()` not the full string

Comment: in any case, why not isdigit?

Comment: @Rakesh I have a bunch of files to process. How can I store each result in a list so I will get at final a list of lists ? Like this for example : [[2, 1, 1, 0, 3],[0, 1, 1, 2, 1],[3, 1, 1, 2, 1]]

Comment: This solution even identifies 'number' when encounter new line, because '/n' with isalpha returns False

Comment: @MejdiDallel .. added snippet. Hope it helps

Comment: This gives false results when I have lines with strings at the end of the file with no numbers after.

Comment: @MejdiDallel. Can you post an example?

Comment: @Rakesh drinking
Just add some text to end of the file.